# What's the distance between this line and this plane

Tags: vectors, 3d, plane-geometry

Find the distance between the line $x=-2+t$, $y=1+2t$, $z=1-t$, and the plane $x+2y+z=5$

I answered with zero, because the line and the plane are not parallel but my professor told me I was wrong. Am I?

My exact answer was:

From the line equation:

$V=\langle 1,2,-1\rangle$ (direction vector)

From the plane equation:

$n=\langle 1,2,1 \rangle$ (normal vector)

$ n \cdot v= (1\cdot 1)+(2\cdot 2)+(1\cdot(-1))=1+4-1=4$ (dot product)

$|n|=\sqrt{1+4+1}=\sqrt{6}$

$|v|=\sqrt{1+4+1}=\sqrt{6}$

$n\cdot v=|n||v|\cos \vartheta$

$θ=\arccos (n\cdot v/(|n||v|))=\arccos (4/6)=48.189$ degrees

The line and the plane are not parallel and so, they must intersect at some point, therefore the distance between the line and the plane is zero.

Comment: The only way to assess your answer is if your work in obtaining it is sound.  Hence, please show your work.

Comment: It was a mid exam that occured 3 days ago. I asked him about it today and that's when he told me I was wrong.

Comment: I'll post my answer shortly.

Comment: Please include your full answer in your question post, and *NOT* as an answer.

Comment: Hello, it's me again. I've edited my question and added my answer. I hope this was what you meant by not posting it as an answer.

Comment: Great!  I appreciate your added work!

Comment: Maybe was $z=1+t$   (?)

Comment: Unless he was mistaken and he did not notice it, then no, Z=1-t.

Comment: Just show your professor that point $(-1,3,0)$ lies both on the plane and on the line.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I thought of this immediately after I exited the exam room and went to my lecture. I just did not know how to find this point. Would you be so kind as to show me how you did it...

Comment: Plug the expressions for $x$, $y$, $z$ into the equation of the plane and solve for $t$ (solution: $t=1$).

Comment: What would happen if the line and the plane were paralleled? Wouldn't I get a value for t?

Comment: Yes, of course: in that case there is no solution.